# Get Azure Security Center tasks via API

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-security, azure-security-center

im trying to write a backend program that will get all of Azure Security Center tasks (Recommendation) with no browser authorization involved.
As far as i saw, Graph API does not have an end point for Security tasks and the only endpoint i could find is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/securitycenter/tasks/list which supports only Implicit flow authorization.
Is there a way to get authorization without using consent window in the browser, or to get the tasks via different endpoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who will need this in the future,
it is possible.
It didnt work for me because i requested the bearer token from the wrong address, use the following url for the bearer token request:

[https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/token](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7BtenantId%7D/oauth2/token)

And NOT:

[https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7BtenantId%7D/oauth2/v2.0/token)
(This is the azure AD typical bearer token request url)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below Powershell script which is using the REST API to get all the tasks:

```
$subscriptionId = "yoursubid"
$context = Get-AzContext
$profile = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstractions.AzureRmProfileProvider]::Instance.Profile
$profileClient = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Common.RMProfileClient -ArgumentList ($profile)
$token = $profileClient.AcquireAccessToken($context.Subscription.TenantId)
$authHeader = @{
    'Content-Type'  = 'application/json'
    'Authorization' = 'Bearer ' + $token.AccessToken
}

$uri = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$subscriptionId/providers/Microsoft.Security/tasks?api-version=2015-06-01-preview"

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri `
                              -Method Get `
                              -Headers $authHeader
$response.value | ConvertTo-Json
```

OR

You can directly use **Azure CLI** to get directly .

```
Command:
az security task list
```

**Reference:**

[az security task | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/security/task?view=azure-cli-latest)

[Install the Azure Az PowerShell module with PowerShellGet | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps?view=azps-6.3.0)

**Output for the above powershell script:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you would rather not mess around with getting the bearer token (and you want to go the powershell route) you can also use `Invoke-AzRestMethod`

```
# Capture everything MDC can do from a REST API
$Capabilities = (Invoke-AzRestMethod -ApiVersion "2022-09-01" -ResourceProviderName 'Microsoft.Security').Content | ConvertFrom-Json
$Capabilities.resourceTypes
```